# I'm getting these weird inaccurate, smeared reflections. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, reflection

I'm using cyces. The background is an Environmental Texture.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is hard to guess what you are doing with the materials on the surface, Can you add an image of the nodes?

Comment: maybe share your file (with the packed images)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to change the normal and roughness materials to Non-Color.